Stream From Firestore to BigQuery
Encountering problems with the latest update
In my previous version of the extension, there was an option available to select the Import existing Firestore documents into BigQuery? and Existing Documents Collection name fields. However, upon installing the new extension for the updated collection, these options are no longer visible. Additionally, after installation, it fails to import the old Firestore data into BigQuery.
Before update

After Update

Furthermore, during the installation of the new extension, there was an option to modify the extension ID. However, today, upon installing a new one, this option is no longer presented. Interestingly, when attempting to install another extension, the same option is provided. I am uncertain as to why this inconsistency is occurring. Please refer to the attached screenshot for clarification.

The import option has temporarily been removed due to this issue #2000. Since you filed the same problem on GitHub yourself too (#2026), I recommend checking #2029 for status updates.

Is it possible for Firestore to update a specific record in BigQuery rather than creating a new row when it is updated in Firestore? Currently, the operation creates a new row in BigQuery with the update operation, but I'd prefer the record to be updated in the same row. Can this be achieved?
